# Dymola Segfault in external C function with Python API when using time and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, modelica, python-c-api, dymola

We execute Python code from Dymola via the [C/Python API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html). Therefore we used that [tutorial](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/interop_c_python.html#calling-external-python-code-from-a-modelica-model). The tutorial works as shown, but when we combine Dymolas built-in time variable and Pythons Numpy library, we get a segfault.

Function in Dymola to call abitrary Python code:

```
function pyString
input String s;
output Real o;
external "C" o = pyRunString(s)
annotation(Include="
#include <Python.h>
double pyRunString(const char *str)
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString(str);
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0.0;
}
");

end pyString;
```

When we call this function with following model it works in the simulation:

```
model CallPython
  Real value;
equation 
  value = pyString("print(" + String(time) + ")");
end CallPython;
```

This model works in the simulation as well:

```
model CallPython
  Real value;
equation 
  value = pyString("import numpy \nprint(" + String(0.0) + ")");
end CallPython;
```

But we get a segfault when we simulate this model:

```
model CallPython
  Real value;
equation 
  value = pyString("import numpy \nprint(" + String(time) + ")");
end CallPython;
```

[image: Segfault from last model]

We are using Ubuntu20.04 with Dymola Version 2021 (64-bit), 2020-04-17, Python3.8 and Numpy 1.21.0

Does anybody know why this does not work or how we can fix it?